# Swift Shorthand for Functions like Flutter?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, shorthand

I was writing out a SwiftUI Button and I was wondering if there's a way I could turn something like this ⤵

```swift
Button(action: {
  self.textField.value?.becomeFirstResponder()
})
```

into ⤵

```swift
Button(action: => self.textField.value?.becomeFirstResponder())
```

#### Clarification

`self.textField.value?.becomeFirstResponder()` [is not a `Void` function.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder#return_value) It is a function of type `() -> Bool`. But it's just used as an example in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` action is of type `() -> Void`:

```
public init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
```

So if your function also is of type `() -> Void`:

```
func buttonAction() {
    // ...
}
```

you can just do:

```
Button(action: buttonAction) {
    Text("Button")
}
```

Otherwise you need to stick what you've already tried or use another `init`.

Comment: Ah I see. I created an updated gist  - 

Cool! So I could write ⤵ as long as the action is `Void` ?

https://gist.github.com/tyirvine/38a7df3c69a7a7453aca6e99a9e8e637

Comment: I'd still need to add the closure to that gist wouldn't I? lol

Comment: @TyIrvine If the return type is different than `() -> Void` then yes, it needs to be in a closure. Only if it's `() -> Void` you can do it the shorter way.

Comment: @TyIrvine Assuming that `self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()` is of type `() -> Void` you could do `Button(action: textField.becomeFirstResponder)...`.

Comment: Okay cool! I think this will be the most useful answer to others. It's pretty cool how Swift can do that!

Answer (score 3):

There is not really much of a choice with the buttons. We have a shorter syntax for the simple text buttons:

```swift
Button("Title") {
    self.textField.value?.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Otherwise, if the button is more complex than the simple text, your example is recommended:

```
Button(action: {
    self.textField.value?.becomeFirstResponder()
}) {
    // Button label here
}
```

There is also a chance to shorten the code depending on what the `textField` is in your case (maybe share a bit more info about that)

Comment: Ah I see. `textField` was just a reference to a `UITextfield` object. It was for this gist another person wrote. It's intent is to provide a larger touch area for the default SwiftUI `Textfield`

https://gist.github.com/Amzd/d7d0c7de8eae8a771cb0ae3b99eab73d#gistcomment-3508020

Comment: Hm, that approach of wrapping UITextField into a weak reference in the gist instead of implementing UIViewRepresentable is a bit controversial. If that would be a proper UIViewRepresentable implementation, we would be able to simplify this button code as much as `Button(action: textField.becomeFirstResponder) { button label }` which is pretty much what you are asking about. But as it is wrapped to a weak container - this can't be done.

Comment: Okay good to know! I will attempt to do this in the future 

Thank you for your help!